# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath - message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have read much topics, but I nothing works.
I have a code, but when I click a cell I get this error:
`*** -[ModeViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x764df40`
Code:
ModeViewController.h

```
@interface ModeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableViewModeSelection;

@end
```

ModeViewController.m

```
@implementation ModeViewController
@synthesize tableViewModeSelection;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
tableViewModeSelection = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, screenRect.size.width - 20, screenRect.size.height - 90) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableViewModeSelection.dataSource = self;
tableViewModeSelection.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:tableViewModeSelection];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

cell.textLabel.text = [modes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"Selected at row: %i", indexPath.row);
}
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the solution but just on a side note, `@interface WoLKiModeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` and `@implementation ModeViewController`. Don't they have to be similar? I mean `@implementation WoLKiModeViewController `

Comment: Now it's similar. I made a mistake. It must be `ModeViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

> -[ModeViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x764df40

This message doesn't say that there is a problem with "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:", it saying that there is a problem with your instance of "ModeViewController", which is deallocated (don't exist anymore) when the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" is being called.

**So the problem is about the life time of your ModeViewController instance.**

Can you show where and how your controller is created and stored?

Comment: I have `ModeViewController` in a UIScrollView. So it is earlier set up. Could that be the problem? And how can I solve this?

Comment: @Luuksweb How do you set it? The error suggest that no one have a strong pointer to the Controller. By the way, a Controller can't go inside a UIScrollView, the Controller is not a View. Its view can go inside the scroll view, but not the controller itself. Maybe that is the source of your confusion.

Comment: It's right I add the view from the viewController, because I can't add the viewController itself. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Luuksweb, that question still hold : "Can you show where and how your controller is created and stored?", no one seams to hold a strong pointer to your View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are adding ModeViewController's view on the scrollview, but releasing the ModeViewController instance itself which is actually the tableview's delegate. So the exception is coming. Solution could be to not release the ModeViewController's instance until the its view is existing.

Comment: I use ARC so I can't change this.